# How to do counts across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have searched for hours for a solution to this mysql user case. I have found many examples but none of them had composite primary keys. I want to do a count across 2 tables and also calculate a difference. Here are the two separate queries

primary key testId, tpId

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, 
       testid, 
       tpid 
FROM   cicdexpecteddocument e 
WHERE  e.testid = 8 
GROUP  BY e.tpid; 

3   8   756abdaa-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
3   8   7ea2b31b-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
1   8   c25780cb-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
2   8   c9f70ed9-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
```

primary key testId, tpId, executionId

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, 
       testid, 
       tpid 
FROM   cicdactualdocument a 
WHERE  a.testid = 8 
       AND a.executionid = 
           'execution-d0c5e270-50f2-472e-a609-ac2c381e0a5f-2020.01.09' 
GROUP  BY tpid; 

2   8   7ea2b31b-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
2   8   c25780cb-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
2   8   c9f70ed9-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
```

I would like to end up with something like

```
3       3   8   756abdaa-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
3   2   1   8   87ea2b31b-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
1   2   -1  8   8c25780cb-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
2   2   0   8   8c9f70ed9-31c0-11ea-9c52-0245f4ff0412
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And note that when providing sample data, short ids are often more easily comprehended than long ones.

Comment: This is not clear. "do a count across 2 tables and also calculate a difference" & "something like" don't fully describe anything. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Knowledge of keys (or other constraints) is not needed to query. What is necessary & sufficient to know is for each table--base & query result--its meaning--what a row in it says about the business situation in terms of column values. (However, when constraints hold, further query expressions also return the same results that otherwise wouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. See below for an explanation.

```
SELECT count_t1, count_t2,
  IFNULL(count_t1, 0) - IFNULL(count_t2, 0) AS diff,
  t1.testid, t1.tpid
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_t1, 
    testid, 
    tpid
  FROM cicdexpecteddocument e
  WHERE e.testid = 8
  GROUP BY e.tpid
) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_t2, 
    testid, 
    tpid
  FROM cicdactualdocument a
  WHERE a.testid = 8 AND a.executionid = 
    'execution-d0c5e270-50f2-472e-a609-ac2c381e0a5f-2020.01.09'
  GROUP BY tpid
) AS t2 ON t1.testid = t2.testid AND t1.tpid = t2.tpid
ORDER BY tpid
```

Dissecting this:

Skip past the `SELECT` columns and notice how the two queries that you specified for each table are contained in parenthesis followed by "AS t1" (or t2) -- those are subqueries. After the 2nd subquery (2nd to last line) is where I specified the join condition.

Next is how the "diff" column is calculated. It uses the `IFNULL()` function which returns the value specified in the 2nd parameter if the primary value is NULL. That allows the database to do the calculation even on NULL values.

**Note:** I just put this together quick and dirty, but I'm not making any assumptions about speed here. If you have a couple hundred rows, no big deal. But if you're dealing with thousands of rows in each table, you may need to work on optimizing this query.

Hope that helps!